# Can we republish messages in PUBNUB

Tags: javascript, python, json, pubnub

I have a situation  where I can get the data from python so I can only publish via python. I need to visualize this data so I need to subscribe to the channel via JavaScript. My visualization libaray C3.js only takes data into the following format:

```
message: {
      columns: [
        ['x', volume],
        ['y', timetamp]
      ]
    }
```

To get my data like this in python is difficult for me. An easier solution would be to subscribe via JavaScript and again republish the data into my desired format. My question is, is it possible to do that in PUBNUB if so DO I need to publish the data into another channel or the same channel would be ok?

My python code is:

```
for each in data:
    y = each.counter_volume
    x = each.timestamp
    pubnub.publish(channel='orbit_channel', message=y)
```

**My Desired Output for is**

```
    message: {
             "columns": [
   ["x", "2015-07-06T13:26:19", "2015-07-06T13:26:19","2015-07-06T13:26:19"],
   ["y", 5000.0, 5000.0, 5000.0]
]
}
```

Comment: Did it work with the script below? Consider making it the accepted answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To get my data like this in python is difficult for me.

That format is JSON and data can be serialized into this pretty easy in Python, try the `json` module:

```
import json
from time import gmtime, strftime

now = str(strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
n = 5000.0

message = {"columns": [["x", now, now, now], ["y", n, n, n]]}
print "message: " + json.dumps(message, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Output:

```
message: {
    "columns": [
        [
            "x",
            "2015-07-16T12:56:47",
            "2015-07-16T12:56:47",
            "2015-07-16T12:56:47"
        ],
        [
            "y",
            5000.0,
            5000.0,
            5000.0
        ]
    ]
}
```

Maybe providing the data like this in the expected way is easier to work with in your JS file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your approach but it gives me the following result which is not my desired output: message: {"columns": [["x", "2015-07-06T13:26:19"], ["y", 5000.0]]}
message: {"columns": [["x", "2015-07-06T13:26:19"], ["y", 5000.0]]}
message: {"columns": [["x", "2015-07-06T13:26:19"], ["y", 5000.0]]}

Comment: My desired out put would be something like above, edit

Comment: You could've modified the scipt yourself, the `json` module is all you need. Changed my answer to match exactly your desired output...